# Erlang: simple pubsub for processes — is my approach okay?

Tags: erlang, publish-subscribe, erlang-otp, extending

Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to Erlang and OTP.

I want a simple pubsub in Erlang/OTP, where processes could subscribe at some "hub" and receive a copy of messages that were sent to that hub.

I know about `gen_event`, but it processes events in one single event manager process, while I want every subscriber to be a separate, autonomous process. Also, I was unable to grok `gen_event`'s handlers supervision. Unfortunately, Google results were full of XMPP (Ejabberd) and RabbitMQ links, so I didn't find anything relevant to my idea.

My idea is that such pubsub model seamlessly maps to supervision tree. So I thought to extend the supervisor (a `gen_server` under the hood) to be able to send a cast message to all its children.

I've hacked this in my quick-and-dirty custom "dispatcher" behavior:

```
-module(dispatcher).
-extends(supervisor).
-export([notify/2, start_link/2, start_link/3, handle_cast/2]).

start_link(Mod, Args) ->
    gen_server:start_link(dispatcher, {self, Mod, Args}, []).

start_link(SupName, Mod, Args) ->
    gen_server:start_link(SupName, dispatcher, {SupName, Mod, Args}, []).

notify(Dispatcher, Message) ->
    gen_server:cast(Dispatcher, {message, Message}).

handle_cast({message, Message}, State) ->
    {reply, Children, State} = supervisor:handle_call(which_children, dummy, State),
    Pids = lists:filter(fun(Pid) -> is_pid(Pid) end,
                 lists:map(fun({_Id, Child, _Type, _Modules}) -> Child end,
                           Children)),
    [gen_server:cast(Pid, Message) || Pid <- Pids],
    {noreply, State}.
```

However, while everything seem to work fine at the first glance (children receive messages and are seamlessly restarted when they fail), I wonder whenever this was a good idea.

Could someone, please, criticize (or approve) my approach, and/or recommend some alternatives?

Comment: Are the messages stored and new processes subscribing get the whole history of them.  Or is it that messages are passed on only from the point of time when a process subscribed?

Comment: The latter; like in Redis or 0MQ Pub/Sub. I'll take another look at `gen_event`, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your code it looks to me that gen_event handlers are a perfect match.

The handler callbacks are called from one central process dispatching the messages, but these callbacks shouldn't do much work.

So if you need a autonomous process with its  own state for the subscribers, just send a message in the event callback.

Usually these autonomous processes would be gen_servers  and you just would call gen_server:cast from your event callbacks.

Supervision is a separate issue, that can be handled by the usual supervision infrastructure that comes with OTP.  How you want to do supervision depends on the semantics of your subscriber processes.  If they are all identical servers, you could use a `simple_one_for_one` for example.

In the `init` callback of the subscriber processes you can put the `gen_event:add_handler` calls that adds them to the event manager.

You can even use the event manager as supervisor if you use the `gen_event:add_sup_handler` function to add your processes if the semantics of this suits you.

Online resources for understanding gen_event better: [Learn you some Erlang chapter](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/event-handlers)

Otherwise the Erlang books all have some gen_event introduction.  Probably the most thorough one you can find in [Erlang and OTP in Action](http://www.manning.com/logan/)

Oh and BTW: I wouldn't hack up your own supervisors for this.

Comment: An example of a process that "supervises" a `gen_event` handler can be found here: http://www.trapexit.org/Gen_event_behavior_demystified

Comment: A problem with event managers is that they can only have at most one of each type of event handler so if you are sending to many of the same type it will be one handler which sends to them all.

Answer (score 11):

I've recently used [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc) to implement pubsub.  The example from the readme does the trick.

```
subscribe(EventType) ->
    %% Gproc notation: {p, l, Name} means {(p)roperty, (l)ocal, Name}
    gproc:reg({p, l, {?MODULE, EventType}}).

notify(EventType, Msg) ->
    Key = {?MODULE, EventType},
    gproc:send({p, l, Key}, {self(), Key, Msg}).
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example where you do it all yourself is in my very basic [chat_demo](https://github.com/rvirding/chat_demo) which is a simple web-based chat server. Look at `chat_backend.erl` (or `chat_backend.lfe` if you like parentheses) which allows users to *subscribe* and they will then be sent all messages that arrive at the backend. It does not fit into supervision trees though the modification is simple (although it does use `proc_lib` to get better error messages).

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes ago, i read about øMQ (ZeroMQ), which has a bunch of bindings to different programming languages.

http://www.zeromq.org/

http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:erlang

If it must not an pure erlang solution, this could be a choice.